# Discussion Forum - Users can't update profile settings

Tags: error, discussion

I'm using the Discussion **Forum 3.1.15 (EE 2.8.1)**.  For some reason, users aren't able to update their profile settings, e.g. Edit Profile, Edit Localization, etc.  When they submit the forms, they get the following error:

> "The action you have requested is invalid."

I noticed this was a bug related to XID values not being present as hidden fields in the forms on EE 2.7.x and Forums 3.1.14, but it was supposedly fixed and those fields are now there.

Is there a configuration tweak or something that I'm missing, or does anyone have any ideas?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please check the default permissions from Admin panel given to your Discussion Forum.